# debuild creates unsatisfiable dependency

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I want to create a deb package of an existing package but with updated code. The origin package has a dependency to `libc`. After running `debuild -us -uc -b` I get the new package but it has a dependency to `libc-amd64`. This library does not exist and I can not install the package. In `debian/control` I see `Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}`.

Ok, `libc-amd64` DOES exist and is already installed, but installation fails:

```
$ sudo dpkg -D400 -i ../apackage_0.23-git20150520_amd64.deb 
Preparing to unpack .../apackage_0.23-git20150520_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apackage (0.23-git20150520) over (0.22-2) ...
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libc6-amd64
D000400:     found 0
D000400:   found 0 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apackage:
 apackage depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.15).

dpkg: error processing package apackage (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

$ dpkg -l  libc6-amd64
ii  libc6-amd64         2.19-0ubuntu6.6                 i386 

$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
$ dpkg -l libc6-dev
ii  libc6-dev:amd64    2.19-0ubuntu6.6       amd64
ii  libc6-dev:i386     2.19-0ubuntu6.6       i386
$ dpkg -l libc6-dev-amd64
ii  libc6-dev-amd64    2.19-0ubuntu6.6       i386
$ dpkg -l libc6-dev-i386
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libc6-dev-i386
```

Comment: What architecture are you using? Run `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` to find out.

Comment: What do `dpkg -l libc6-dev`, `dpkg -l libc6-dev-amd64` and `dpkg -l libc6-dev-i386` produce? Please [edit] your question to add the information.